# Is there a star catalog for download?

Tags: astronomy, resource-recommendations, data

Is there a downloadable star catalog which not only includes positions, but also spectral class, size, etc.? A CSV file would be great for the sake of easiness.

Comment: What have you found yourself so far? Looked at Wikipedia, for instance? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_catalog

Comment: This request is pretty unspecific. How deep do you need the catalog (and are you measuring by magnitude or distance)? Will partial sky coverage suffice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be what you are looking for:  http://astronexus.com/node/34

Answer (score 0):

Here is [one from NASA](http://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/db-perl/W3Browse/w3table.pl?tablehead=name%3Dbsc5p&Action=More+Options).

I remember that there was an option for extracting CSV table.